# ExtJS set the height of tab panel to 50%

Tags: extjs

I'm new to ExtJs and I'm trying to position two tabpanels within a panel. Each of the panels will have to be 50% height of the parent panel. I can't seem to find any way to do this. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use [vbox layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox) with the same [`flex`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox-cfg-flex) value on both tabpanels.
[See example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#layout-vertical-box).